# map multiple keys, same value

Tags: java, dictionary

I am populating a map and each entry becomes every entry. I do not know how this happened.

```
public Map<Register, String> regFileList = new HashMap<Register, String>();
    /** $zero always zero (by hardware) */
    public Register zero = new Register(0);
```

// .... plus all other registers declared ...

```
private void populateRegFileList(){     
        zero.setRegNumber(0);
        zero.setRegName("$zero");
        zero.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(zero, zero.getWord());
        at.setRegNumber(1);
        at.setRegName("$at");
        at.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(at, at.getWord());
        v0.setRegNumber(2);
        v0.setRegName("$v0");
        v0.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(v0, v0.getWord());
        a0.setRegNumber(3);
        a0.setRegName("$a0");
        a0.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(a0, a0.getWord());
        a1.setRegNumber(4);
        a1.setRegName("$a1");
        a1.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(a1, a1.getWord());
        a2.setRegNumber(5);
        a2.setRegName("$a2");
        a2.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(a2, a2.getWord());
        a3.setRegNumber(6);
        a3.setRegName("$a3");
        a3.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(a3, a3.getWord());
        a4.setRegNumber(7);
        a4.setRegName("$a4");
        a4.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(a4, a4.getWord());
        s0.setRegNumber(8);
        s0.setRegName("$s0");
        s0.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(s0, s0.getWord());
        s1.setRegNumber(9);
        s1.setRegName("$s1");
        s1.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(s1, s1.getWord());
        s2.setRegNumber(10);
        s2.setRegName("$s2");
        s2.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(s2, s2.getWord());
        s3.setRegNumber(11);
        s3.setRegName("$s3");
        s3.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(s3, s3.getWord());      
        k0.setRegNumber(12);
        k0.setRegName("$k0");
        k0.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(k0, k0.getWord());
        sp.setRegNumber(13);
        sp.setRegName("$sp");
        sp.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(sp, sp.getWord());
        fp.setRegNumber(14);
        fp.setRegName("$fp");
        fp.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(fp, fp.getWord());
        ra.setRegNumber(15);
        ra.setRegName("$ra");
        ra.setWord("0x00000000");
        regFileList.put(ra, ra.getWord());
        System.out.println(regFileList);
    }
```

prints: {$ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000, $ra =0x00000000}

Any ideas on how this happens? If I move the print statement up to an earlier point, it prints the correct number of entries, but all identical.

Comment: How are the equals and hashcode methods of Register implemented?

Comment: Can you share equals () in register?

Comment: Where do you initialize the variables? Is every register initialized with `new`? The `regName` and others aren't declared `static` are they?

Comment: Show us the Register class. Show us how the registers are defined. Tell us what you expect to be printed.

Comment: Andres has a good point. What's the point of associating the word of a register with its register in a Map? If you have an instance of a Register, you just need to call `register.getWord()` to get its word. So the map is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, as you´re not showing where are the instances being created.

However, a couple of considerations concerning your question:

- It´s clear that at some point of your program, you're making all the variables you add to the map to point to the same object. Probably the one you created last.
- Check that the map works the way you wanted. Most surely it makes more sense to use the String as a key and the Register as the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you nailed with the variables - that was the step I missed. I have been so diligent about that and missed it when it really counts. Thanks!!!
The purpose of the map is to use this set of registers separately from others. This is a simulator that has several types of registers. The map includes those in the registerfile and I need to be able to display them. They are mapped with their addresses. 
I have 3 types of registers: AbstractRegister (super for all registers), Register (all registers that have no microcode), and RegisterSpecialty (have microcode with signals to enable/disable them when they are called during the fetch/decode/execute cycle). I did this because I noticed that the registers that had no signals were automatically disabled.

public class Register extends AbstractRegister{

```
/** register number */
private int regNum;
/** 32 bit32 address in hex format */
private String word;
/** name of register */
private static String regName;
```

/**
    * 
    * constructor Register
    */
    public Register() {
    regName = getRegName();
    word = getWord();
    }

/**
    * 
    * constructor
    * Register
    * @param num
    */
     public Register(int num){
    setRegNumber(num);
    }

```
 /**
  * increment   
  * @param string 
  * @param more2
  * @return 
  */
   public String increment(String string) {
String s = string.trim();
s = string.replaceFirst("0x", "");
int src1 = Integer.parseInt(s);
Micro.DrALU.setFlag("1");
String s1 = "0x" + new ALU().input(src1, 1, 0b00);
return s1;
}


 /**
  * setRegNum
  * @param regSel the regSel to set
  */
  public void setRegNum(int regNum) {
this.regNum = regNum;
}

 /**
  * 
  * setRegName
  * 
  * @param name
   */
 public void setRegName(String name) {
regName = name;

}


 /**
  * @return the regName
  */
 @Override
  public String getRegName() {
return regName;
}


  /**
  * @return the word
   */
   @Override
   public String getWord() {
return word;
}

  /**
   * @param word
   *            the word to set
  */
  @Override
public void setWord(String word) {
if(word != null){
    this.word = word;
    }else{
    word = "0x00000000";
    }
}

 /**
  * 
  */
@Override
public String toString(){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(getRegName());
sb.append(" ");
//      sb.append(getRegNum());
    //      sb.append(" ");
    //      sb.append(getWord());
    return sb.toString();

}

 /**
  * setRegNumber    
  * @param i
  * @return
  */
  public void setRegNumber(int i) {
    regNum = i;

}

 /**
  * getRegNum
  * @return the regNum
  */
  public int getRegNum() {
return regNum;
}


 /**
  * valueOfNumber   
  * @param reg   * @return
  */
  public int valueOfNumber(Register reg) {
return this.regNum;
}

 /**
  * valueOf 
  * @param trim
  * @return
  */
   public String valueOf(String name) {
setRegName(name);       
return name.toString();
}
}
```